# Usar una factory de controladores en PHP y romper dependencias para su uso, a pesar de los include o require

Tags: php, dependencias

Tengo una duda difícil de explicar.

Supongamos que tengo una clase en php:

#### file: claseA.php

```
<? 
claseA {
    //mi codigo de la clase
}
```

y tengo una factory que crea la instancia:

#### file: myFactory.php

```
<? include 'claseA.php'
miFactory {
    //getInstanceOfA () {
    //codigo para retornar una instancia unica de A...
}
```

Ahora, para usar la factory que me devuelva la claseA, debo incluir la factory, supongamos:

#### index.php

```
<? require_once 'myFactory.php';

$factory = new Factory();
$factory->getInstanceOfA(); //un codigo que funciona
```

**EL PROBLEMA:**

En este index, al tener los require de cada archivo,
tambien podría hacer:

`$instanciaDeAsinUsarFactory = new claseA(); // y tambien funciona!!!`

***Como puedo romper esas visibilidades a pesar de la necesidad de los include?***

Answer (score 0):

No se trata del autoload (ya intente con eso)

Se trata de que cada include de otro include hace que todo el codigo sea "visible" desde lugares donde no debería serlo

Los includes y los require los declaro al inicio de cada script php, como paliativo lo que hice fue en el getInstanceOfClaseA() { //include ControllerClaseA.php}

Para que de esa forma, debes si o si pedir la instancia para que se incluya el archivo que contiene el controllerclaseA

Igual no se si es la solucion más "correcta" en cuanto a la arquitectura de la solucion (una fabrica con instancia única que provee una instancia unica de cada controlador con un getInstance para cada controlador, el archivo index.php solo debería conocer la Interface para saber los methodos cumplidos para esa interfaz y obtener la instancia de la Fabrica)

Es una cuestión de diseño, ya que funciona pero no debería funcionar si no es por medio de la obtención de la instancia que provee la fabrica. ¿Me explique bien?

Igual muchas gracias

Comment: Hola jose, Stack Overflow no funciona como un foro en el que haya que postear mensajes cada vez. Si quieres puedes dejar un comentario en la publicación de Diego Avila, o edita tu pregunta para añadir nueva información, pero no publiques una respuesta en tu propia pregunta para añadir información nueva (a no ser que lo que quieras poner sea una respuesta). Lee [ask] y [answer] para más información, y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio (y con ello ganar tu primera medalla).